# sync method undefined laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, eloquent, pivot-table

I have a relationship in my laravel application,

```
//Organsiation __has_many__ users (members)
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('is_admin');
}


public function organisations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Organisation')->withPivot('is_admin');
}
```

When I edit an organisation I try and sync the `organisation_user table` using,

```
$organisation->users()->sync($members);
```

The argument passed looks like this,

`array(1 => array('is_admin' => 1))` as it states in the laravel documentation.

However I getting the following error returned from the server,

```
BadMethodCallException","message":"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::sync()
```

I am wanting to use `sync` as if my `$members` array contains new members, or doesnt contain an existing member, it will update the pivot table correctly, what I cannot understand is why it is not working.

I thought `sync()` was meant for many-to-many relationships?

Comment: All your code looks totally correct to me. Are you sure you pasted everything correctly and `$organisation->users()->sync($members);` is really causing the error? (any other calls to `sync()`?)